# Calling multiple values from inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, global-variables

Im trying to call for some values from inside of a function but
`global` is giving me more errors

```
def init():
    Rounds = input("enter the amount of rounds: ")
    while Rounds.isnumeric() == False or int(Rounds) <= 0:
        Rounds = input("enter a valid value: ")
    Rounds = int(Rounds)

for i in range (Rounds):
    None
```

its not just one variable, I have about 6 that I need to call after the function.
here `Rounds` in the `for loop` is showing an error saying it is not defined.

Comment: Return `Rounds` in `init`. Then call the `init` inside the `for`s range. Keep away from `global` as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `Rounds` is a local variable and is only defined inside
`init` to fix that you can make it global with:

```
def init():
    global Rounds
    Rounds = input("enter the amount of rounds: ")
    while Rounds.isnumeric() == False or int(Rounds) <= 0:
        Rounds = input("enter a valid value: ")
    Rounds = int(Rounds)

for i in range(Rounds):
    None
```

Answer (score 0):

If need to access Global variables, need to mention `global` before them

```
Rounds = None

def init():
    global Rounds
    Rounds = input("enter the amount of rounds: ")
    while Rounds.isnumeric() == False or int(Rounds) <= 0:
        Rounds = input("enter a valid value: ")
    Rounds = int(Rounds)

init() # call method to populate Rounds

for i in range (Rounds):
    None
```

Safer way

```
def init():
    Rounds = input("enter the amount of rounds: ")
    while Rounds.isnumeric() == False or int(Rounds) <= 0:
        Rounds = input("enter a valid value: ")
    Rounds = int(Rounds)
    return Rounds


for i in range (init()):
    None
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `global`, using `global` is a bad practice. Just return the value from `init`:

```py
def init():
    rounds = input("enter the amount of rounds: ")
    while rounds.isnumeric() == False or int(rounds) <= 0:
        rounds = input("enter a valid value: ")
    return int(rounds)

Rounds = init()
for i in range(Rounds):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, it's not a good idea to make a local variable in a function a global one. In fact, the `global` keyword should be used as little as possible. It can cause trouble in some cases. You have a better way in achieving this:

```py
def init():
    global Rounds
    Rounds = input("enter the amount of rounds: ")
    while Rounds.isnumeric() == False or int(Rounds) <= 0:
        Rounds = input("enter a valid value: ")
    return int(Rounds)

for i in range(init()):
    None
```

Or if you want to use `Rounds` elsewhere, try this:

```py
def init():
    global Rounds
    Rounds = input("enter the amount of rounds: ")
    while Rounds.isnumeric() == False or int(Rounds) <= 0:
        Rounds = input("enter a valid value: ")
    return int(Rounds)

# In python 3.8+
for i in range(Round := init()):
    None

# In python 3.7
Round = init()
for i in range(Round):
    None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def init():
global Rounds
Rounds = input("enter the amount of rounds: ")
while Rounds.isnumeric() == False or int(Rounds) <= 0:
    Rounds = input("enter a valid value: ")
Rounds_int = int(Rounds)

for i in range(Rounds_int):
    pass
```

You needed to add global and in for i in range (Rounds):
None you had space